# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable

'The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't' pleas can any one help me with this error.
i faced this error will trying to make extracting widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'quote.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(
  home: QuoteList() ,
));

class QuoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuoteList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuoteList> createState() => _QuoteListState();
}

class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {

  List<Quote> quotes = [
      Quote(text: 'This is the quote number 1',author: 'Ahmed Maged'),
      Quote(text: 'This is the quote number 2',author: 'Kareem Khaled'),
      Quote(text: 'This is the quote number 3',author: 'Ahmed Shoman'),
  ];

  Widget quoteTemplate(quote){
    return QuoteCard(quote: quote);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: const Text(
          'List of Data',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            letterSpacing: 2.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontFamily:'FiraSans',
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: quotes.map((quote) => quoteTemplate(quote)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuoteCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Quote? quote;
  const QuoteCard({super.key, this.quote});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text(
                quote.text, // error part
                style: const TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 2.0,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 6.0,),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    quote.author, // error part
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

this is the qoute file
quote.dart file:

```
class Quote {
  String? text;
  String? author;

  Quote({required this.text, required this.author});

}
```

it just alisson from the net ninja lesson number #20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error in Flutter occurs when you are passing a nullable string (String?) to a function or method that expects a non-nullable string (String). To resolve the error, you can either make sure the string being passed is not null or update the function or method to accept a nullable string. You can also use the ?? operator to provide a default value for the string in case it is null.
try this:

```
 Text(
                quote.author??"", // error part
                style: const TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 2.0,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                ),
```

and this

```
 Text(
            quote.text, // error part
            style: const TextStyle(
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
```

the solution for your commented error is

```
class QuoteCard extends StatelessWidget {
final Quote quote;
const QuoteCard({super.key,required this.quote});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Card(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text(
            quote.text, // error part
            style: const TextStyle(
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 6.0,),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Text(
                quote.author, // error part
                style: const TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 2.0,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontFamily: 'FiraSans',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error

Error: Property 'author' cannot be accessed on 'Quote?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'Quote' is from 'package:list_data/quote.dart' ('lib/quote.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
                    quote.author??"",
                          ^^^^^^

Comment: check the answer now i updated it.